Что делать если у моего Tool Не проигруетса анимация в самом роблоксе тоисть В роблокс студио она работает а в самом роблоксе нет
то делать если у моего Tool Не проигруетса анимация в самом роблоксе тоисть В роблокс студио она работает а в самом роблоксе нет //////я ето пишу чтобы моё сообщение приняли

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Итить-колотить!

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
